# Can I transfer a profile onto a different PS3 account?

Tags: ps3

My dad set up a PS3 profile for me a while ago on his PS3 with an account he made since I didn't have my own e-mail address at the time.

Now I have my own PS3 and e-mail address and would like to transfer my old profile onto my own PS3.  Since it's under one of my fathers accounts I'm not sure if I am able to get it.

Are multiple profiles on PS3's in separate accounts from each other or are they all under the same account on a PS3?  If they are all under the same account is there a way to transfer a profile onto a different account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are a different thing from PSN accounts:

- [Users exist only on that ps3 and keep saves and stuff separate](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/users/users.html).
- [PSN accounts are tied to an email address and have to do with store purchases, friends lists, trophies, and online activity](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/account/signup.html).
- Only one user per PS3 can be associated with one PSN account. A second user cannot have the same PSN account. A single user cannot access multiple PSN accounts. https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/348/~/use-different-sign-in-ids-(e-mail)

There's also the mess with sub-accounts too. Your description is fairly unclear as to the whole setup you've got going on. Multiple users have to have separate accounts if they have accounts associated with them at all. There isn't a way to merge accounts, but there are ways to transfer and update both accounts and users.

Here are your options, depending upon your situation:

1. You have an existing PSN account and want to associate it with a new PS3:

   Create a new user on your new PS3 and [sign in to the existing
   account](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/account/associate.html).
2. You have an existing PSN account and want to change the email address:

   [Go to PSN/Account Management/Account Information/Sign-In ID (E-mail
   Address) and change your email
   address](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/255).
3. You are trying to transfer saved data from one PS3 to another:

   [Save and copy what you can to external storage](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/game/copysavedata.html) so you can transfer it straight across. Backing up non-save data is essentially the same as backing up save data.
   As long as you back-up/sync trophies to PSN, when you sign in on the new system, it will sync those across.
   For the rest you may have to use [the data transfer utility](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/transferutility.html) which is fairly involved.
4. You have no PSN account, but want one:

   [Go to PSN/Sign up](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/account/signup.html). If the user to transfer the data of in option 3. does not have a psn account, you will need to create one so this would apply during that process.